# How to get tag name and its corresponding attributes as a key:value pair from a xsd file

Tags: python, xml

if xsd file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xbrldt="http://xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt" xmlns:num="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/numeric" xmlns:nonnum="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/non-numeric" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:ifrs="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2012-03-29/ifrs" targetNamespace="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2012-03-29/ifrs" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"> 
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/numeric-2009-12-16.xsd" namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/numeric"/> <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/nonNumeric-2009-12-16.xsd" namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/non-numeric"/> 
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd" namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"/> <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt-2005.xsd" namespace="http://xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt"/> 
<xsd:element xbrli:periodType="duration" type="nonnum:domainItemType" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" name="AbnormallyLargeChangesInAssetPricesOrForeignExchangeRatesMember" id="ifrs_AbnormallyLargeChangesInAssetPricesOrForeignExchangeRatesMember" abstract="true"/> 
<xsd:element xbrli:periodType="duration" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" name="AccountingProfit" id="ifrs_AccountingProfit" xbrli:balance="credit"/> 
<xsd:element xbrli:periodType="instant" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" name="Accruals" id="ifrs_Accruals" xbrli:balance="credit"/> 
<xsd:element xbrli:periodType="instant" type="xbrli:monetaryItemType" substitutionGroup="xbrli:item" nillable="true" name="AccrualsClassifiedAsCurrent" id="ifrs_AccrualsClassifiedAsCurrent" xbrli:balance="credit"/> 
</xml>
```

i need a dict in this format

```
d={'AbnormallyLargeChangesInAssetPricesOrForeignExchangeRatesMember':{'xbrli:periodType':'duration','type':'nonnum:domainItemType','substitutionGroup':'xbrli:item'}}
```

like this for each element it should print attribute "name" as tag and rest all attributes as a value of that tag..

i am trying to do with any xml parsers , i know how to do using re....... but i need it through any xml parsers only..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a sax parser:

```
import xml.sax

class MyXsdHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def parse(self, f):
        self.result = {}
        s = open(f, "r").read()
        xml.sax.parseString(s, self)
        return self.result

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == "xsd:element":
            d = dict(attrs)
            self.result[attrs["name"]] = d

results = MyXsdHandler().parse("myfile.xsd")
```

in this case the dictionary for an element contains all attributes. you could pick the ones you're interested in yourself or use a dictionary comprehension to filter the attributes if you're using python 3:

```
interestingAttrs = ["type", ...] #all attributes you need
#inside the if in startElement
#python 2:
d = dict()
for a in interestingAttrs: d[a] = attrs[a]

#python 3:
d = {a: attrs[a] for a in interestingAttrs}
```

One important thing to note: the 'attrs' object in startElement is not a dictionary, it just works in a similar way for accessing attributes. But you can't actually set values and it's missing some other functionalities of dicts, so you should always create a dictionary of the attributes if you're doing more than just printing the attributes.

Comment: @-l4mpi thanks a lot this what i was looking... i made some changes its working fine as expected...

Comment: @-l4mpi but where ur calling startelement function, what are the parameters contains in that function... can u explain that it will be useful for me thanks

Comment: The `startElement` function gets called by the parser at the beginning of every element. The parameters are the name of the Element and the Attributes. Similarily, there are functions like `endElement` and `characters` that get called for closing tags and text data in elements. see [here](http://www.knowthytools.com/2010/03/sax-parsing-with-python.html) for a tutorial.

Comment: ok thanks.......last doubt,can above function be called through this method "parse(filename_or_stream, handler[, error_handler])"